# htaccess to resolve a trailing slash to .html page

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to resolve a page to it's .html equivalent if someone removes the extension and adds a trailing slash?

http://www.example.com/page.html

http://www.example.com/page/ **<-- adding trailing slash**  resolve to page.html.

However, I want the trailing slash to be optional and not something that I add in htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on

# render .php as .html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]

# don't need extension on the end
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

# .php to .html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# .php to .html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R=301]

# don't need extension on the end
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  http://www.example.com/page/ now resolves to html page.  What would I need to also add to also resolve http://www.example.com/page.html / (with the slash with .html)

Comment: Makes sense, I see you just added the trailing slash.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I have one more question.  I'm forwarding non-www to www and non-http to https.  It works fine, but Google is warning "Avoid landing page redirects"  Is there a way to combine?  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: Is there anyway to update the above to reverse not needing an html extension on the end?  And then 301 forward if not?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make the trailing slash optional for html requests, you can use :

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: When I add the trailing slash, the page errors to:  http://www.example.com/.php/.html/